# python2.7 manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm using **python 2.7** and am having trouble running the server. I have entered

`python2.7 manage.py runserver` and got the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I went into the `manage.py` portion of the app and can see that I have

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myesite.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

can someone please explain what I have done wrong or what I need to do?

Comment: Do you have Django installed on the system?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the django package installed? go to your command line and type "pip list" and see if django is in the list.

If it is not, "pip install django" should allow you to download and install the package.

Comment: when I run pip install django I get a nasty error message any idea why?